# How Can I show a field of sql consult with comma separation and without repeat fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this tables:

TABLE tema

```
+---------+-------------+
| tema_id | nombre      |
+---------+-------------+
|       1 | Aprender    |
|       4 | Justicia    |
|       2 | Pensamiento |
|       3 | Vida        |
+---------+-------------+
```

TABLE frase

```
+----+----------+----------------------------------------+
| id | autor_id | texto                                  |
+----+----------+----------------------------------------+
|  1 |        2 | Pienso, luego existo                   |
|  2 |        1 | Aprender sin pensar es trabajo perdido |
+----+----------+----------------------------------------+
```

TABLE tema_frase (relation with table frase and tema)

```
+----------+---------+
| frase_id | tema_id |
+----------+---------+
|        1 |       2 |
|        2 |       1 |
|        2 |       2 |
+----------+---------+
```

So when I perform this consult:

```
SELECT frase.texto, tema.nombre 
FROM tema_frase INNER JOIN
     tema 
     ON tema_frase.tema_id = tema.tema_id INNER JOIN
     frase 
     ON frase.id = tema_frase.frase_id
```

I get this:

```
+----------------------------------------+-------------+
| texto                                  | nombre      |
+----------------------------------------+-------------+
| Pienso, luego existo                   | Pensamiento |
| Aprender sin pensar es trabajo perdido | Aprender    |
| Aprender sin pensar es trabajo perdido | Pensamiento |
+----------------------------------------+-------------+
```

My question is, how can I show a consult in this way?

```
+----------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| texto                                  | nombre                |
+----------------------------------------+-----------------------+
| Pienso, luego existo                   | Pensamiento           |
| Aprender sin pensar es trabajo perdido | Pensamiento, Aprender |
+----------------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to group the result and use `group_concat` to concatenate the names:

```
SELECT frase.texto,group_concat(tema.nombre separator ", ")
FROM tema_frase 
INNER JOIN tema 
ON  tema_frase.tema_id=tema.tema_id 
INNER JOIN frase 
ON frase.id=tema_frase.frase_id
GROUP BY frase.texto
```

You can also order alphabetically and avoid duplicates using `group_concat`:

```
SELECT frase.texto,group_concat(DISTINCT tema.nombre separator ", " ORDER BY tema.nombre ASC)
FROM tema_frase 
INNER JOIN tema 
ON  tema_frase.tema_id=tema.tema_id 
INNER JOIN frase 
ON frase.id=tema_frase.frase_id
GROUP BY frase.texto
```